# Framework 7 popup not working

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I am creating an app and I want to open a dynamic popup when I click on a div.

So I used the code that is given by Framework7 at https://framework7.io/docs/popup.html#examples.

What happens is that nothing happens.
If I use the code for About Popup or Services Popup it works, but if I use the dynamic one nothing happens.
I even tried to add a console log inside **$$('.dynamic-popup').on('click', function () {** to check if it executes the function but nothing. No log.

Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got the example working by assigning the click handler only after the `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired like so:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    $$('.dynamic-popup').on('click', function () {
        dynamicPopup.open();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in app.js

```
var dynamicPopup = app.popup.create({
  content: '<div class="popup">'+
              '<div class="block">'+
                '<p>Popup created dynamically.</p>'+
                '<p><a href="#" class="link popup-close">Close me</a></p>'+
              '</div>'+
            '</div>',
  on: {
    open: function (popup) {
      console.log('Popup open');
    },
    opened: function (popup) {
      console.log('Popup opened');
    },
  }
});
```

Above code creates dynamic popup.
To call dynamic pop-up on click event.

```
$$('.dynamic-popup').on('click', function () {
  dynamicPopup.open();
});
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks alot. By the way I need to pass a var to the popup that is an attribute (data-id="123") of the a.dynamic-popup. How can I do this?

Thanks